# os.scandir and multiprocessing - ThreadPool works, but multi-process Pool doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, scandir

I have a task in a Python script that was previously mostly IO-bound, so I used ThreadPools and everything worked fine. Now my task is becoming more CPU-bound, so I wanted to switch to Pools with multiple processes.

I thought both interfaces behaved virtually identically, so I just switched the import and I should be good to go. However, suddenly my worker function isn't getting executed in the pool anymore.

After trying a couple of things, this seem to correspond with the fact that I'm passing a DirEntry from os.scandir() to my worker function. Replacing the 'entry' with a hardcoded string, my worker function is executed. Replacing it back with entry, it stops working. Replacing the import with ThreadPool, it works again.

```
# This works.
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
import os

pool_size = 3

def worker(entry):
    print("Did some useful stuff!")

pool = Pool(pool_size)

for entry in os.scandir("Samples/"):
    if entry.is_file():
        pool.apply_async(worker, (entry,))

pool.close()
pool.join()

print("Finished multiprocessing task.")
```

Output:

```
Did some useful stuff! (~150x)
Finished multiprocessing task.
```

Replace `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool` with `from multiprocessing import Pool`, the only output I now get is:

```
Finished multiprocessing task.
```

Now, if I insert a random string instead of the entry from the loop into `pool.apply_async(worker, (entry,))`, so e.g. `pool.apply_async(worker, ("Why does this work?",))`, the worker function works and returns the same output as with the ThreadPools, but obviously with the argument I don't want to use in my actual script.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, stuff that gets passed to a child process is being pickled, and that does not work for `DirEntry` resulting from `scandir`. Unfortunately with `apply_async` you do not get to see corresponding failures. You would with simple `apply` and that is how I tracked this down, once you see what is going on, it actually does make sense:

```
TypeError: can't pickle posix.DirEntry objects
```

Depending on what you want, you can pass `entry.path` or other attribute(s) (that can be pickled, so really, also `name` or you'd have to use return values of its methods) of `DirEntry` into your worker and your code should work OK as is.

---

As for learning about failures, alternatively, you could write a small function such as:

```
def print_failed(caught):
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
```

And register it with your `apply_async` call by adding: `error_callback=print_failed`.

Comment: Ugh, so this basically shows that ThreadPools and Pools are not *quite*  directly replaceable  with each other. Kind of a bummer, because I liked the ability to switch between the file name and the full path with the `DirEntry` objects. But yeah, seems like I have to change my code a bit to work with the attributes and not the whole object. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, but they really cannot be the same, because threads share the same address space and hence passing content is much simpler. Once you spawn individual processes, passing has to happen across process boundaries. If ability to switch is important, you needs to stick to pickleable stuff that'll work in either case.